# How to write a templated version of this slicing code of Eigen?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, optimization, eigen3

This slices `MatrixXd` with a `Array<bool, Dynamic, 1>`, just like in Matlab you can do `A(A>5)`, here you can do `slice(A, A.array() > 5)`. I'd like to turn this into a templated version, so that it can take any type of matrices or vectors, for instance `Matrix3i` or `VectorXi`. This page tell me to use `MatrixBase<Derived>`, but I was not able to get very far with it. Idk how to declare a templated matrix of a certain size. 
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;

MatrixXd slice(const MatrixXd & mat, const Array<bool, Dynamic, 1> & ind)
{
    assert(mat.cols() == ind.size());
    // find out dimensions of the matrix going out
    int _cols = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < ind.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(ind[i] == 1)
        {
            _cols += 1;
        }
    }
    //populate the matrix going out, in a column major way
    int _pos = 0;
    MatrixXd out = MatrixXd::Zero(mat.rows(), _cols);
    for(int i = 0; i < ind.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(ind[i] == 1)
        {
            out.col(_pos) = mat.col(i);
            _pos += 1;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

And usage is like this:

```
MatrixXd A(4, 4);
A << 1,2,3,4,
     5,6,7,8,
     1,5,6,3,
     9,8,6,5;
VectorXd b(4);
b << 23,-4,1234,3;
cout << A << endl;
cout << (b.array() > 5) << endl;
cout << slice(A, b.array() > 5) << endl;
```

Output is as such:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
1 5 6 3
9 8 6 5
1
0
1
0
1 3
5 7
1 6
9 6
```

I'd appreciate if anyone would show me how to do this!

PS: There seems to be a similar functionality in the docs:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html
But I was literally unable to find the keyword `all` in Eigen/Core, as

```
std::vector<int> ind{4,2,5,5,3};
MatrixXi A = MatrixXi::Random(4,6);
cout << "Initial matrix A:\n" << A << "\n\n";
cout << "A(all,ind):\n" << A(all,ind) << "\n\n";
```

And my IDE is unable to resolve it either.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If possible, you should further simplify your code, to avoid anything related to "eigen" as many ppl may not know, what exactly is it. Keep only the minimal code part for better understandability.

Comment: I have edited my question, but this is directly related to Eigen3, as there are some very specific ways of doing things for that library, and that is what I am interested in.

Comment: So you are not looking for `Eigen::Block(...)`, which can get sub-sections of a Matrix?

Comment: You could use `Eigen::Block` to get individual blocks, or in my case the columns vectors, but I think that you cannot use `Eigen::Block` to extract multiple columns arbitrarily in one go.

Comment: "but I was not able to get very far with it" how far did you get? Please show your attempt and the errors you get. It is much easier to answer if you post non working code and the errors rather than your working code and we have to guess what is your problem

Comment: By "not far with it", i meant basically nowhere. In particular I wanted to construct an output of the same type than the input, but of a certain fixed size. So basically I blocked at how to call the constructor of `MatrixBase<Derived>`.

Comment: `Eigen::all` only works with the current development branch (and will work with Eigen3.4 once it gets released). If you want to return by value, the return type you are looking for is something like `Eigen::Matrix<typename Derived::Scalar, Derived::RowsAtCompileTime, Eigen::Dynamic, Derived::MaxRowsAtCompileTime, Derived::MaxColsAtCompileTime>`. If you want to return a lazy expression, it will get much more complicated.

Comment: thanks, that helps, i'll update my question as soon as i have more time to try this out.

Comment: I guess for now I'll use for the non-templated version, the easiest path is often to do nothing. Does anyone have an idea when Eigen 3.4 will come out?